# Array vs vector, memory layout

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Could somebody confirm the difference between:

```
class A{
    public:
        std::vector<int> a;
        std::vector<int> b;
};
```

and

```
class B{
    public:
        std::array<int, 1000> a;
        std::array<int, 1000> b;
};
```

Class `A` the object contains two pointers to two randomly-allocated regions on the heap?

In contrast the second class the object would have continuous memory allocated (depending where the object was- stack or heap) for both arrays, which would be continuous. The arrays would be located next to each other (which would not be the case with class `A`)?

Comment: Basically, yes, though a) `std::vector` would typically store more than a single pointer, and b) it is not guaranteed that `B::a` and `B::b` would have no padding between them (though in practice that would most likely be the case).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Also, the vector stores its data in a contiguous block of memory as well…

Comment: Thanks everyone. Feel free for somebody to put an answer and i'll accept.  @Igor Good point about vector doesn't just have a single pointer!

Comment: @user997112: I've added an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the vector instances inside an instance of `class A` will contain something along the lines of three pointers [or two pointers and a `size_t` aka `std::vector::size_type`, or one pointer and two `size_t`]. Storage for elements in the `std::vector<int> a, b` will be allocated from the heap. Content of `a` and `b` are far from guaranteed to be close to each other. Each element within `a` and `b` will be stored consecutively, so aside from the extra pointer dereference, for example, cache-locality will be very similar between the two solutions.

However, if you do something like

```
A x;
x.a.resize(1000);
x.b.resize(1000);
```

on a fresh heap, chances are that `a` and `b` are indeed not very far apart.

In an instance of B, there will be two arrays, each big enough for 1000 integers, potentially with some padding between them. The arrays will be next to each other, aside from padding.